# AWS CDK2 code to publish the json message into SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sns, aws-cdk-typescript

I am looking to publish json message into SNS from AWS CDK2 code, but not finding any way.

i can do through Axios call or using aws-sdk, but i need to do through cdk as we are going to create this as Cfn template and then use it through API integration.

so it will be helpful if we can do this in CDK.

Appreciate your help.

I was able to send message through Axios and aws-sdk.

Comment: That is not easily possible, CDK / CloudFormation cannot generate SNS messages. What you can do is have a custom resource / lambda which you thereby invoke and that lambda could interact with SNS. What specifically do you need to send a notification for? Can that not e.g. be achieved by configuring an EventBridge rule?

Comment: We are trying to send Json message after completion of cloud formation stacks to cross account SNS, which will be process further by other subscribes.

Comment: AWS CDK is used to create AWS Resources - not interact with them like the SDK Service clients do.

Comment: Then you should just use EventBridge and configure a rule that matches what you are interested in.

Comment: yes, i am working on to use Event Bridge

Comment: Look into CDK Triggers as well.